# Is there a plug-in for any iDE to view Freemarker templates locally?

Tags: freemarker

I am a front-end dev making a freemarker template. I would like to build and view without having to make a new Maven project, Tomcat servers etc.. just to see what my html looks like. Not sure if this is possible

Comment: As far as I know you would need to have a local setup to do this. Look on the bright side, you only need to do this once

Comment: Usually you also need the data-model (the variables that the template sees) to author templates. So generally templates meant to be tried with the real application or with whatever mock the application developers made. (This is also why FreeMarker supports modifying templates without restarting the application.)